# Where are `kAFAssistantErrorDomain` codes documented?

Tags: macos, error-code, sfspeechrecognizer

I'm trying to work with `SFSpeechRecognizer` on macOS.

I'm getting error messages such as:

```
ERROR in Dictation.swift: Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=209 "(null)"
ERROR in Dictation.swift: Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
```

How to interpret these error messages?  I cannot find the codes enumerated anywhere in the documentation.